# Update dict but if duplicate key increase list[0] value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have 2 dictionaries with the following format:

```
a = {'steve': [1, 'jones'], 'harry': [2, 'smith']}

b = {'jasper': [1, 'jones'], 'harry': [1, 'smith']}
```

I want to update dict `b` with `a` while if there are duplicate keys I want to add the `value[0]` of `a` and `b` together.

So `b` would end up like:

```
b = {'jasper': [1, 'jones'], 'harry': [3, 'smith'], 'steve': [1, 'jones']}
```

It must be an update and **should not** create a new dict each time, like:

```
a = {x: [y[0] + y[0] if x in b else y[0], y[1]] for x, y in b.items()}
```

Comment: Just wondering. Not `b = {'jasper': [2, 'jones'], 'harry': [3, 'smith'], 'steve': [1, 'jones']}`, but `b = {'jasper': [1, 'jones'], 'harry': [3, 'smith'], 'steve': [1, 'jones']}`. Right?

Comment: is it garantueed that each key (i.e. 'harry') has always an identical second item in the list (i.e. 'smith')? If not how should that be resolved?

Comment: That's a bad data structure.  What are you going to do if `a` had a harry jones in it?

Comment: Yes @sangheestyle thanks I've edited. This isn't the exact data structure I will be using but I thought it would be suitable for resolving the problem i'm having. In the event there are not identical items in the list then ideally it would be appended to the end of the list in b.

Comment: @johnnydrama I see. I think if we can change the data structure as another guy mentioned, it might be easy to do. What do you think about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using `collections.Counter` as values for the structure. That allows for easy addition and it allows to have multiple values for each key:

```
from collections import Counter

a = {'steve': Counter({'jones': 1}), 'harry': Counter({'smith': 2})}
b = {'jasper': Counter({'jones': 1}), 'harry': Counter({'smith': 1})}
```

I said it makes it easier to do the addition, check it out:

```
for key, val in b.items():
    try:
        a[key] += val
    except KeyError:
        a[key] = val

print(a)
#{'harry': Counter({'smith': 3}),
# 'jasper': Counter({'jones': 1}),
# 'steve': Counter({'jones': 1})}
```

You might even go a step further and use a `collections.defaultdict` for `a`, that makes the `try` and `except` in the iteration obsolete:

```
from collections import defaultdict

a = defaultdict(Counter, {'steve': Counter({'jones': 1}), 'harry': Counter({'smith': 2})})

for key, val in b.items():
    a[key] += val

print(a)
#defaultdict(collections.Counter,
#            {'harry': Counter({'smith': 3}),
#             'jasper': Counter({'jones': 2}),
#             'steve': Counter({'jones': 1})})
```

Answer (score 1):

As other said, you are using a bad structure. Maybe a better structure is this:

```
a = {'steve': {'jones': 1}, 'harry': {'smith': 2}}

b = {'jasper': {'jones': 1}, 'harry': {'smith': 1}}
```

this way you just need to check if the key exist and eventually increase the value else you create a new key in the dict